# Kafka enable.auto.commit values for each consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I just got in Kafka and I was wondering if we should have enable.auto.commit to true or false. Is there anything which drive us to a specific solution or it's something which is upon us.
Is there any option to have default as true and then if for a consumer is needed for us to commit it after processing/transforimg to set it to false. I found out that we could use 2 different ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory , but is it the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how strongly you want to guarantee data is processed.

If you set it to true, and catch and ignore some exception in the middle of processing, you could lose up to hundreds of offsets, by default, per poll. You'd need to seek the consumer backwards to catch any missed data, but then re-process any successful events as well.

If you set it to false, and forget to commit, then you could re-process the same data again and again. If you commit after every message, then you'll slow down the consumer rather significantly.

You cannot change the value at runtime without closing the consumer thread(s) and re-initializing with new configs.

Comment: When using Spring, we recommend it being `false` (current versions will default to that, if not explicitly set). The listener container will perform the commits in a more deterministic fashion - using `AckMode.BATCH` (default) or `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: @GaryRussell does that mean if we have it set to `true`, it will auto commit on the configured interval that is setup. Otherwise (if set `false`), it will use `AckMode.Batch`, which means lets say if it fetched `max.poll.records`=500, it will commit automatically after these 500 records are processed (the type of listener `batch` or `single` does not matter here)?

Comment: If it's true, the container won't commit any offsets at all; the `kafka-clients` will do it using its properties; correct, the listener type is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is my understanding correct above for the `max.poll.records` and `AckMode.Batch`? I guess by correct you meant that all i have written above is OK? What do you mean about `kafka-clients`? Isn't the container that does the consuming client as well?

Comment: The `kafka-clients` is the jar containing `KafkaConsumer`; the container uses that consumer to consume the records; if the auto commit property is set to true, the container ignores the `AckMode` and relies on the `KafkaConsumer` to do its own committing. Yes, when I said "correct" I meant yes, what you wrote is correct.